# Installing Kivy app on Win10 does not seem to get python from Virtualenv

Tags: python, kivy, virtualenv, pyinstaller

I have written a Kivy app (simplified below) using a virtual environment with python3.7, which is a Kivy requirement. My system however uses python3.8. The Kivy app works and is using python3.7 as required.

I have used Pyinstaller as per the instructions [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html) and everything runs fine.

My problem is that once the app is built and I double-click the .exe a window briefly opens and closes, then nothing happens.

I don't know if this is the problem, but when I look in the `/dist` directory I see `python38.dll` which leads me to think Pyinstaller has picked up the wrong version of python. If that is the case, then I think Pyinstaller probably hasn't picked up anything else from my Virtualenv. I am not expert enough to know if this is the problem or not, or how to make Pyinstaller use my Virtualenv or a different python interpreter.

Here is the code etc for reference.

Kivy App

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Play(App):

    def build(self):
        l = Label(text="Hello World")
        return l

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Play().run()
```

Pyinstaller spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

# byx start
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
# byx end

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\mark\\OneDrive\\dev\\babyclix\\_staging\\_test\\simple.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\mark\\OneDrive\\dev\\babyclix\\_staging\\_test'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='winkivy',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True, 
          icon='C:\\Users\\mark\\OneDrive\\dev\\babyclix\\_staging\\_test\\logo.ico')

# byx start
# Add the Tree statements for all dependencies. Everything in the directory gets added.
# 1st -- The home directory with scripts, byx, icon.    
# 2nd -- Kivy dependencies, a list of directories. 
coll = COLLECT(exe,
                Tree('C:\\Users\\mark\\OneDrive\\dev\\babyclix\\_staging\\_test\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
                *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='winkivy')
# byx end
```

Here is the log from the Pyinstaller build.

```
.venv) c:\Users\mark\OneDrive\dev\babyclix\_staging\_test>python -m PyInstaller main.spec  
122 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0
122 INFO: Python: 3.8.0
123 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
126 INFO: UPX is not available.
142 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\mark\\OneDrive\\dev\\babyclix\\_staging\\_test',
 'C:\\Users\\mark\\OneDrive\\dev\\babyclix\\_staging\\_test']
176 INFO: checking Analysis
177 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
177 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
183 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
213 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6077 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
6219 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
6224 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
6609 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\mark\OneDrive\dev\babyclix\_staging\_test\main.py
6711 INFO: Processing module hooks...
6712 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\mark\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6829 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\mark\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7171 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
7177 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
7185 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\mark\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
7192 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
7398 INFO: Looking for eggs
7399 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python38.dll
7400 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
7413 INFO: Warnings written to c:\Users\mark\OneDrive\dev\babyclix\_staging\_test\build\main\warn-main.txt
7464 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to c:\Users\mark\OneDrive\dev\babyclix\_staging\_test\build\main\xref-main.html
7485 INFO: checking PYZ
7486 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
7486 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) c:\Users\mark\OneDrive\dev\babyclix\_staging\_test\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz
8171 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) c:\Users\mark\OneDrive\dev\babyclix\_staging\_test\build\main\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
8189 INFO: checking PKG
8189 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
8190 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
8221 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
8223 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
8224 INFO: checking EXE
8224 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
8227 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
8239 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\\Users\\mark\\OneDrive\\dev\\babyclix\\_staging\\_test\\logo.ico']
8327 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 90 bytes
8327 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 17255 bytes
8328 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 67624 bytes
8328 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 16936 bytes
8329 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 9640 bytes
8334 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 4264 bytes
8335 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 1128 bytes
8339 INFO: Appending archive to EXE c:\Users\mark\OneDrive\dev\babyclix\_staging\_test\build\main\babyclix.exe
8421 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
8425 INFO: checking Tree
8429 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
8429 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
8435 INFO: checking Tree
8435 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
8435 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
8437 INFO: checking Tree
8438 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
8438 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
8442 INFO: checking Tree
8448 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-03.toc is non existent
8448 INFO: Building Tree Tree-03.toc
8452 INFO: checking COLLECT
8452 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
8453 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
8990 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem is not to do with Kivy or PyInstaller but with VSCode and the way it choses python interpreters.

Basically the *Terminal Window* in VSCode does not necessarily use the python interpreter you selected in the palette, or in your activated virtual environment. So if your app is version sensitive or you are expecting the venv to be used within the *Terminal Window* you may have problems.

This problem has been raised in many places but is never answered correctly, people jump to the conclusion the person asking the question is asking how to "select a python interpreter" and answer the question by saying "use the command palette". This does not solve the "Terminal Window" problem.

Note also, the python interpreter shown in the status bar is also not the answer, that is the interpreter used to run your app. Your app may run perfectly, but you still have the *Terminal Window* problem.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600928/how-can-i-get-my-vscode-terminal-to-use-my-venv-for-python-rather-than-the-syste) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98252).

I am going to close this question and ask a more specific question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64688164/make-vscode-terminal-window-use-right-python-interpreter).