# How to configure VS Code's Integrated Terminal to use the correct Python Interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

##### TL;DR

This question is ***NOT*** asking how to select a *Python Interpreter* to run, or debug, code with, furthermore; this question is ***NOT*** asking anything in regard to *Virtual Environment*, or how to activate a *Virtual Environment*, all of that is working. I feel it is important to note, that the question below has been asked previously, but failed to receive a satisfying answer due to confusion over what was being asked. Community Members often think one of the questions, that I mentioned at the beginning of this question, is being asked, here is a question that's a good example of what I just wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64653963/installing-kivy-app-on-win10-does-not-seem-to-get-python-from-virtualenv).

---

#### Here is My Question:

###### How can a user configure their Integrated Terminal to use an Interpreter that the user specifies?

I want to be able to configure my terminal to use the interpreter in my virtual environment — their is an example of my virtual environments interpreter in the Screenshot below.

1. from the status bar that the VENV interpreter is active, and my code runs fine.
2. from the *Windows Terminal* the system interpreter is being used.

[image: VSCode using different interpreters]

The problem that is caused by this, is that I can't run pip or other packages like *PyInstaller* from the *Integrated Terminal* because its not looking inside of my VENV, and furthermore; I don't want to globally install the packages.

Another problem that occurs is that, parts of my app include version sensitive packages, and I need to control the version of the python interpreter used by the *Integrated Terminal*.

Comment: What do you see in the Terminal if you, after starting python, check `sys.executable`? And what you would like it to be?

Comment: @Mark Kortink -What happens when you reopen VSCode? Have you tried using other virtual environments? Please try to refresh the terminal several times.

Comment: @Jill Cheng - I have rebooted VSCode multiple times and restarted the terminal window multiple times, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @np8 - ```sys.executable``` returns my system interpreter "'C:\\Users\\mark\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe'". I want the terminal window to use the interpreter in my venv, but in general point it to any interpreter I chose, my venv directory is "C:\Users\mark\OneDrive\dev\babyclix\.venv\Scripts". As the screen shot shows, terminal uses 3.7.7 and venv 3.7.0.

Comment: The "Terminal" in VS Code is just cmd.exe or Powershell (in most cases). In this case, it seems to be cmd.exe. It seems that for some reason there is a path in the PATH environment variable, which contains a folder with wrong python.exe, even after the activation of the venv. Open cmd.exe, check output of `echo %PATH%`. Then, run `C:\Users\mark\OneDrive\dev\babyclix\.venv\Scripts\activate.bat` and check `echo %PATH%` again. What did change? The first folder with `python.exe` is the one started when you run `python`.

Comment: Check all the folders that are before `C:\Users\mark\OneDrive\dev\babyclix\.venv\Scripts`. There you should find the reason for the described behaviour.

Comment: @np8 - The only difference between the path with venv activated is that the venv directory is put at front. The python interpreter is the same further down the path. The *terminal* does not seem to be searching the venv for a python interpreter.

Comment: After activating the `.venv` in `cmd.exe`, what is output of `where python`? After activating `.venv` in VS Code terminal, what is output of `where python`? Is there any difference?

Comment: One sinple thing that comes to my mind is that it could be that VS code does some magic behind the scenes if you select an interpreter, but does not pass the change to Terminal windows that are already open. After selecting interpreter, open a *new* Terminal window, and activate the .venv. Does it work then correctly?

Comment: @np8 - After activating venv in cmd.exe I get the venv interpreter 3.7.0, while in VSCode I get the system one. The ```where python``` command returns nothing in cmd.exe,  and the system interpreters in VSCode. Changing the interpreter to the venv one and restarting VSCode does not change the Terminal interpreter.

Comment: A workaround for me would be to install into venv from cmd.exe, as when I run my app in VSCode it does use the venv, it is just the terminal that doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure you activated .venv before `where python` in `cmd.exe`? It would mean that it does not find any `python.exe` and should throw an error if you try to run `python`.

Comment: What is the VSCode version you are using? I use VS Code with Terminal and virtual environments every day and never ran into any problems. If I could reproduce the problem it would be easier to find a fix.

Comment: @np8 - VSCode 1.50.1. Yes the venv in PowerShell is activated and ```where python``` doesn't give an error, it just returns nothing. The command ```python``` returns  the venv python version. I have used VSCode and Terminal a lot without problem as well. You should be able to reproduce it by installing python3.9 or some version you don't have on your machine, including it in your path, rebooting VSCode, and type ```python``` in the Terminal to see what version it is picking up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224222/discussion-between-np8-and-mark-kortink).

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesnt really answer the question but it may be of some help to some people, so here it is.

I have no idea what im doing but I finally fixed this issue...
my issue was that I was trying to get the default interpreter to use python 3 instead of python 2.

I ended up deleting python 2 from my PATH...

in the end I realized that the path changed to this after I deleted Python 2, so maybe the solution can be found here.

[maybe this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eUi9.png)
{
"python.pythonPath": "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe",
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though [another integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487445/how-to-change-the-integrated-terminal-in-visual-studio-code) could be configured such that a python environment setup script is executed.  This would establish the python environment to the venv that is desired.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode's Integrated Terminal is either `cmd.exe` or PowerShell; it will simply use the first python.exe (or py.exe) found in the `PATH` environment variable.

This means that you want to run a script (batch file or PS1 script) upon starting the Terminal to modify the `PATH` env var.

In order to do that, follow the tips in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71512662/149900

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have both interpreters installed, lets say that interpreter 2 is located in C:\User<your_user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311

STEPS:

1. Create a VENV using the interpreter2 path.

   - Choose a directory for you virtual env.
   - Once inside that directory, type:

   C:\Users\<your_user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m venv /path/to/venv

   - This will create a VENV with interpreter2 inside.
2. Use it with VSCode.

   - Open the integreated terminal inside VSCode.
   - type the command to activate the VENV you created earlier:

   /path/to/venv/Scripts/activate.bat
3. Once you do that, your VSCode will be running the second interpreter.

PS: Bellow there is a Screenshot of my own set where I had the Default 3.11.8 version running, but I switched to the VENV using 3.11.5
[image]